# Create a heatmap for VISN level data in R

Tags: r, heat-map

I am trying to create a heatmap for Veterans Integrated Service Networks (VISN) level averages. I have found [these datasets](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/veterans-integrated-services-networks-visn-markets-submarkets-sectors-and-counties-by-geog) containing shapefiles.

I have the averages I want to plot based on the VISN, but I'm not sure how to go about creating this map in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `sp.kde` in the spatialEco package will produce a weighted or unweighted Kernel Density Estimate (KDE), or what you are calling a "heat map". Please note that this works for point feature classes, not polygons or lines.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)
  data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
```

Weighted KDE using cadmium and spatial locations without a reference raster

```
cadmium.kde <- sp.kde(x = meuse, y = meuse$cadmium, bw = 1000, n = 5000, 
                      standardize = TRUE, scale.factor = 10000  )
```

Unweighted KDE (spatial locations only)

```
pt.kde <- sp.kde(x = meuse, bw = 1000, standardize = TRUE, n = 5000, 
                 scale.factor = 10000  )
```

Plot results

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(cadmium.kde, main="weighted kde")
    points(meuse, pch=20, col="red")
  plot(pt.kde, main="Unweighted kde")
    points(meuse, pch=20, col="red")
```

Using an existing raster

```
data(meuse.grid)
  coordinates(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
  proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
  gridded(meuse.grid) = TRUE
  meuse.grid <- raster(meuse.grid)

  cadmium.kde <- sp.kde(x = meuse, y = meuse$cadmium, newdata = meuse.grid, 
                        bw = 1000, standardize = TRUE, scale.factor = 10000  )
```

Plot results

```
dev.new()                     
  plot(cadmium.kde, main="weighted kde")
    points(meuse, pch=20, cex=0.5, col="red")
```